# Saving an Image to MYSQL Blob field

Tags: c#, mysql, image, insert, blob

I have a C# Windows Application that stores Employee Data into a MYSQL Database including their pictures. But the pictures are not saving when trying to Insert an Image file to a MYSQL Blob field.

Please help. Here's the code.

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "\\\\192.168.13.6\\ID Pictures";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        int size = -1;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                pnl_Picture.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(file);
             }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }

                conn.Open();
                FileStream fs;
                BinaryReader br;

                byte[] ImageData;
                fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                br.Close();
                fs.Close();

                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_employee        (Picture) VALUES ('"+?Image2+"')", conn);
                OdbcParameterCollection parameters = command.Parameters;
                parameters.Add("?Image2", OdbcType.Image);
                parameters["?Image2"].Value = ImageData;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Save the image path instead.

Comment: That's what I did before. The files' path were the one saved on the database. But I had trouble in displaying the images on my crystal reports. That's why I decided to save the Image itself and not the path.

Comment: Showing the images on your reports shouldn't be a problem as long as you are referencing the correct file path and getting the file name from the db.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to display images on crystal reports 10 using a file path stored in the database?

Comment: [Crystal Reports With Dynamic Images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wpvd5vHF8Pg)

Answer (score 0):

There is MySql [provider](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/index.html) for Visual Studio instead Odbc.
You can add parameters like so:

```
 parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Image2", ImageData));
```

Comment: I tried parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("Image2", ImageData));
Returned no error but still not saving the Image on the database.

Comment: So, try to use MySql provider first.